# Has anyone used xdpi, ydpi and gotten correct results

Tags: android

I'm wondering if anyone out there has used xdpi and ydpi and gotten the actual physical dpi of the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is correct on my Nexus One, but not on my Galaxy S2 (T-mobile).  So I wrote some code to fall back on the less accurate measurement.  Basically, if xdpi and ydpi are not within 5% of the generic density, use the generic.

Who says fragmentation isn't a problem?  Google's product test suite for certification must not exercise this part of the API.

```
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
  float density = dm.density;
  density = density * 160;
  float xdpi = dm.xdpi;
  float ydpi = dm.ydpi;
  float errX = Math.abs((xdpi / density) - 1f);
  float errY = Math.abs((ydpi / density) - 1f);
  if (errX > .05 && errY > .05)
  {
     xdpi = density;
     ydpi = density;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't. xdpi and xdpi are totally wrong in all phones I've tried it on. It makes no sense.